# Замена подстроки на другую на лету

Tags: регулярные-выражения, строки, replace

Здравствуйте! Кто-нибудь сталкивался с ситуацией когда необходимо было заменить маску подсети в префикс через слеш.( то есть предусмлотреть все возможные варианты) 
в примере три случая,

```
set address "UntrustGn" "172.30.2.130/32" 172.30.2.130 255.255.255.255
set address "UntrustGn" "190.8.35.230/32" 190.8.35.230 255.255.255.248
set address "UntrustGn" "217.118.69.0/24" 217.118.69.0 255.255.255.0
```

привести к виду

```
set address "UntrustGn" "172.30.2.130/32" 172.30.2.130/32
set address "UntrustGn" "190.8.35.230/32" 190.8.35.230/29
set address "UntrustGn" "217.118.69.0/24" 217.118.69.0/24
```

Сначала, мне надо было извлечь соответствующие строки. Это сделал регулярками.
а как в соответствующих строках делать нужную замену длинной маски на префикс?

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(opendialog.FileName);
string patternZone = @"set address "".*"" "".*"" [0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+( [0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+)";

var matchesZone = Regex.Matches(reader.ReadToEnd(), patternZone);

foreach (var match in matchesZone)
{
    txt.AppendText(match.ToString().Replace(" 255.255.255.255", "/32")+ Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Маска вида `/X` - это количество подряд идущих единиц в октетах представления `X.X.X.X`.

Стало быть задача сводится к переводу октетов в двоичное представление и подсчету единиц.

Пример на JavaScript:

```
var mask="255.255.255.248";
mask.match(/(\d+)/g) //получили октеты
    .map(function(el){return (~~el).toString(2);}) //перевели в bin
    .join('') //склеили двоичные символы
    .lastIndexOf('1')+1; //нашли последнюю позицию символа '1'
```

Результат: `29`

Сразу оговорюсь - корректно переводит только валидные маски.

Comment: Какое извращение! +1.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку ваш код выглядит как C#, переведу код из ответа @Mi Ke Bu на C# (и немного подгоню под стиль, принятый там):

```
var mask = "255.255.255.248";
var result =
    Convert.ToString(
        BitConverter.ToInt32(
            mask.Split('.')
                .Select(byte.Parse)
                .Reverse()
                .ToArray(),
            0),
        2)
    .LastIndexOf('1') + 1;
```